# Widevine Modular with Video.js

Tags: html5-video, video.js, drm, widevine

I'm trying to play a Widevine encrypted MPEG-DASH video, on my webpage, using `Video.js`. I have the generated `.mpd` file in S3 and pass the url as I'm supposed to, but get a 403 forbidden error. It's not a permissions issue with AWS, since if I point directly to the `.mp4` proxy file, `Video.js` plays the encrypted version of the video. When I look at the `mpd` file it seems to separately specify the audio and video files.

Does the audio file need to be separate from the video file in S3?